# Flow type for a Map?

Tags: flowtype

I have a function that expects a Map as in input, how can I type this in Flow?

```
const myFunction = (map: Map) => {
    // do stuff
}

const myMap = new Map([['key', 'value']]);

myFunction(myMap);
```

Feels a standard thing to do but I couldn't find out how on the Flow docs.

Comment: For reference, the `Map` type is declared in [`core.js` in the Flow repo](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/706e83b1dd3f8014e4408096713c43eb3f282c2f/lib/core.js#L594).

Answer (score 1):

The `Map` type takes two type arguments, one for the type of its keys and one for the type of its values. In your example, they are both `string`.

```
const myFunction = (map: Map<string, string>) => {
    // do stuff
}

const myMap = new Map([['key', 'value']]);

myFunction(myMap);
```

([playground](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwGIFczCgS3DAvDACjgEMAHALhgFkyAeaAJ0zAHMAaGR5lgPgEo8PGAG8AUDAkwA9FJgATEJygoAZitEBfUaNCRYiGqTwwwAUwDu1MgQDaNgOQBrUwnsd7AN2IAbFKfsAugF8ANzaiKjoWOBECIahQA))

Comment: Hm what's the deal with `$SymbolToStringTag` error when trying to use a map with strings or numbers as key?

Comment: Oh maybe because I'm trying to use `{}` instead of `new Map`